# Optimize nonlinear model fit

Tags: r

I would like to find the best parameters to fit a curve to my data and I feel like I have everything set up pretty well, but when I run my optimization function, I just get back the starting parameters.

```R
rick<-function(x, a, b){
        x*a*exp(-x/b)
   }

x<-df$WaterInput
a<-.1
b<-460

pred<- rick(t, a, b)
predD<-as.data.frame(pred)
predD$WI<-df$WaterInput

plot(WUEs~WaterInput, data=df)
points(predD$WI, predD$pred, type="p", col="red") 


### Optimization attempt###

obfun<- function(coef, x){

    sim<- rick(x=x, a=coef[1], b=coef[2])
    simD<-as.data.frame(pred)
    simD$day<-df$WaterInput

    obs<- df$WUEs

    rss <- sum((obs - simD$pred)^2)
    rss
}

op.wi<- optim(c(.1, 460), obfun, x=df$WaterInput)
```

The dataframe can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/kns2h2zcqtagwns/WUE%20for%20SO.txt?dl=0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's simply because you don't use the coefficients in your optimization. Right now you are calling `rick()`, then assigning the returned value to `sim`, but then you do not use it in your objective function, `rss`. Also you have a `t` in your example, that you didn't supply.

I think you want something like:

```
rick <- function(x, a, b){
        x*a*exp(-x/b)
}

x <- df$WaterInput
a <- .1
b <- 460

pred <- rick(x, a, b)
predD <- as.data.frame(pred)
predD$WI <- df$WaterInput

plot(WUEs~WaterInput, data=df)
points(predD$WI, predD$pred, type="p", col="red") 

obfun <- function(coef, x){
    sim <- rick(x=x, a=coef[1], b=coef[2])
    obs <- df$WUEs
    rss <- sum((obs - sim)^2)
    rss
}

op.wi <- optim(c(.2, 460), obfun, x=df$WaterInput)
points(x, rick(x, op.wi$par[1], op.wi$par[2]),col=3)
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the following is an alternative for you (but you will need good starting values für a and b)

```
dat <- read.table("WUE for SO.txt", header=TRUE)

mod <- nls(WUEs ~ WaterInput*a*exp(-WaterInput/b), 
           data=dat,
           start=list(a=0.1,b=500))

plot(WUEs ~ WaterInput, dat)

tt <- 100:1300
lines(tt, predict(mod, list(WaterInput = tt)))

summary(mod)

Parameters:
Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
a 8.384e-02  7.065e-03   11.87   <2e-16 ***
b 4.977e+02  3.414e+01   14.58   <2e-16 ***
```

[image]